# Why runtime.caller(0) is giving different path with '--cover' argument in unit testing

Tags: go

When trying to execute a unit test function without any argument it  give following output path

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Go1.8\bin\go.exe" test -v gclassec/skyline/loggers -run ^TestCreateLogFilesPath$

filePath:=== C:/GerritNew/goclassec/src/gclassec/skyline/loggers/logs.go
```

But when I try to run it with any argument such as `--cover` the file path value changes as below:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Go1.8\bin\go.exe" test -v --cover gclassec/skyline/loggers -run ^TestCreateLogFilesPath$

filePath:=== gclassec/skyline/loggers/_test/_obj_test/logs.go
```

I am using `runtime.caller(0)` to get file path.

Comment: Because cover rewrites the sources and works on a different directory than plain `go test`. (Not worth an answer.)

Comment: What should I do so that cover will rewrite the source in same location?

Comment: You cannot and there is no need too. (Or you have to patch the go tool.)

Comment: Please suggest some links regarding unit testing and mocking of variables.

Comment: Your original question is pretty much unrelated to testing. `runtime.caller(0)` is **not** the right way to determine the current working directory (CWD). The CWD is set properly during `go test`, no matter whether `--cover` is used or not. Take a look at how the std library approaches testing. Most probably you are looking for `./testdir`.

Comment: Thanks for help, some how I solve it by using os.Getwd().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by using os.Getwd() and runtime.caller  with a variable to diffrentiate between testing and normal running.